# Verify user provided password with MySQL database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, hash, passwords, pbkdf2

I use c# to design a login window for a GUI, in which user first provides username and password, and the program matchs it with the predefined userlist in the MySQL database. If correct, then the user is permitted to open the GUI.

I found the password is hashed and salted by "PBKDF2-SHA256" algorithm in MySQL. So, for a user with username and password both equal to `test`, by debugging, I found the hashed password from MySQL is of this form:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$12000$d8D3H2ZczGuG$H/U3ioBaeUeYPCP2YqLwpkjI40PoMHqeJyPORz8prUg=
```

I know that it uses `pbkdf2_sha256` to hash the password, salt it by `d8D3H2ZczGuG` with `12000` iterations, and the final result is `H/U3ioBaeUeYPCP2YqLwpkjI40PoMHqeJyPORz8prUg=`. So, when verifying a password, I expect my program first hashes the input password with these same algorithm and parameters, and if the obtained final result is the same as `H/U3ioBaeUeYPCP2YqLwpkjI40PoMHqeJyPORz8prUg=`, then that means the password is correct. For the c# implementation of `pbkdf2_sha256 algorithm`, I used directly [this](https://gist.github.com/peteroupc/6986999) one.

**My code is as follows**:

(the textbox to input username is named as "TextBox_Username" while the password box is named as "PasswordBox_Password"):

```
string server = "127.0.0.1";
string database = "myDatabase";
string uid = "supervisor";
string password = "12345";
string connectionString = "server=" + server + ";" + "database="+database + ";" + "uid=" + uid ";" + "password=" + password + ";";
MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Password FROM myTable_Usertable WHERE Username='" + this.TextBox_UserName.Text + "';";
sqlConnection.Open();
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;

MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    string dbUserPassword= reader[0].ToString();

    string[] passwordString = dbUserPassword.Split("$");
    int iterationCount = Convert.ToInt32(passwordString[1]);
    string saltString = passwordString[2];
    string dbPasswordString = passwordString[3];
    int dkLength = 44;

    byte[] inputPasswordByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.PasswordBox_Password.Password);
    byte[] saltByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltString);
    byte[] hashedPasswordByte = PBKDF2Sha256GetBytes(dkLength,inputPasswordByte,saltByte,iterationCount);
    byte[] dbPasswordByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dbPasswordString);

    if( hashedPasswordByte == dbPasswordByte)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login succeed!");
        MainWindow.show();   
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid password!");
    }

}

// this following function is from the above link
private static byte[] PBKDF2Sha256GetBytes(int dklen, byte[] password, byte[] salt, int iterationCount)
    {
        using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(password))
        {
            int hashLength = hmac.HashSize / 8;
            if ((hmac.HashSize & 7) != 0)
                hashLength++;
            int keyLength = dklen / hashLength;
            if ((long)dklen > (0xFFFFFFFFL * hashLength) || dklen < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dklen");
            if (dklen % hashLength != 0)
                keyLength++;
            byte[] extendedkey = new byte[salt.Length + 4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, extendedkey, 0, salt.Length);
            using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < keyLength; i++)
                {
                    extendedkey[salt.Length] = (byte)(((i + 1) >> 24) & 0xFF);
                    extendedkey[salt.Length + 1] = (byte)(((i + 1) >> 16) & 0xFF);
                    extendedkey[salt.Length + 2] = (byte)(((i + 1) >> 8) & 0xFF);
                    extendedkey[salt.Length + 3] = (byte)(((i + 1)) & 0xFF);
                    byte[] u = hmac.ComputeHash(extendedkey);
                    Array.Clear(extendedkey, salt.Length, 4);
                    byte[] f = u;
                    for (int j = 1; j < iterationCount; j++)
                    {
                        u = hmac.ComputeHash(u);
                        for (int k = 0; k < f.Length; k++)
                        {
                            f[k] ^= u[k];
                        }
                    }
                    ms.Write(f, 0, f.Length);
                    Array.Clear(u, 0, u.Length);
                    Array.Clear(f, 0, f.Length);
                }
                byte[] dk = new byte[dklen];
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Read(dk, 0, dklen);
                ms.Position = 0;
                for (long i = 0; i < ms.Length; i++)
                {
                    ms.WriteByte(0);
                }
                Array.Clear(extendedkey, 0, extendedkey.Length);
                return dk;
            }
        }

    }
```

But now the problem is, the hashed output of my program for the same password is different from the MySQL database's. For instance, for the password as "test", my program gives this output (after converting the output byte to string):

```
?7??ZyG?<#?b??H??C?0z?'#?G?)?Ht\r5_[?% y
```

while the MySQL output is this one (as mentioned above):

```
H/U3ioBaeUeYPCP2YqLwpkjI40PoMHqeJyPORz8prUg=
```

So it says the provided password is incorrect even to a correct password. I guessed maybe my program's output is hexidecimal, so I tried to convert the both my final result with MySQL string to hexidecimal by this:

```
string hexDbPassword = BitConverter.ToString(dbPasswordByte);
string hexHashedPassword = BitConverter.ToString(hashedPasswordByte);
```

The result is this (again not the same):

```
hexDbPassword = 48-2F-55-33-69-6F-42-61-65-55-65-59-50-43-50-32-59-71-4C-77-70-6B-6A-49-34-30-50-6F-4D-48-71-65-4A-79-50-4F-52-7A-38-70-72-55-67-3D    
hexHashedPassword = 1F-F5-37-8A-80-5A-79-47-98-3C-23-F6-62-A2-F0-A6-48-C8-E3-43-E8-30-7A-9E-27-23-CE-47-3F-29-AD-48-02-74-0D-35-0E-5F-5B-02-DC-25-20-79
```

What I am doing wrong here??

Comment: Isn't MySQL password **Base64** encoded? Your one is not. Anyway there is something I don't understand: WHO stores password in MySql? If you're the one who stores it then values will always match...

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean though. I store those passwords into Mysql as administrator using Django.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand **why** you're using Django admin if your app is in C#...you'll need to handle (and to deploy) such extra complexity when you can do everything C# side, whatever is your front-end (to save few lines for user management screen?). Anyway password is hashed, salted and then encoded in base64. In your C# code you're missing last step then they won't match (I didn't read your code so I'm assuming everything else is correct).